# SQL Query: Customer Table Contains Different type of EmpIDs and i want to get their name in a single row

Tags: sql

I got a customer table and each customer has 4 different employeeID (tranieeID,RepresenterID,CoridatorID and ManagerID) I want to get all these employees name rather then their ID in single row.

```
CustomerTable
|CustomerID|CustomerName|tranieeID|RepresenterID |CoridatorID |ManagerID
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 01          Mr T          100         101           102         103



EmployeeTable
EmpID | EmpName
---------------
100     Mr A
101     Mr B
102     Mr C
103     Mr D
```

What I need

```
CustomerID | CustomerName | tranieeName | RepresenterName | CoridatorName | ManagerName
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
01            Mr T              Mr A           Mr B              Mr C            Mr D
```

I did inner join but I got 4 Rows, is there any way to get all these with a single row?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Join `EmployeeTable` to `CustomerTable`  5 times to decode every xx_Id

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JOIN` should work.  I would recommend `LEFT JOIN` in case any of the values are not filled in:

```
select c.*,
       et.empname as traineeName,
       er.empname as RepresenterName,
       ec.empname as CoridatorIDName,
       em.empname as ManagerName
from customertable c left join
     employeetable et
     on c.traineeID = et.empid left join
     employeetable er
     on c.RepresenterID = et.empid left join
     employeetable ec
     on c.CoridatorID = ec.empid left join
     employeetable em
     on c.ManagerID = em.empid
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a correlated subquery in each instance, such as

```
select c.CustomerId, CustomerName,
  (select Empname from EmployeeTable e where e.EmpID=c.TranieeId) TraineeName,
  (select Empname from EmployeeTable e where e.EmpID=c.RepresenterId) RepresenterName,
  ... etc
from CustomerTable c
```